# Spring boot &Hibernate, can't autocreate tables

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using spring boot for  my project so i don't have any .xml to configure. I do all with .properties, for example i define settings for the DB connection in this properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
spring.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.datasource.initialize=true 
spring.error.whitelabel.enabled=true
hibernate.dialect:org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
#portale.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.database=DEFAULT
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

#PORTALE
portale.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/portale?
transformedBitIsBoolean=true
portale.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
portale.datasource.username=root
portale.datasource.password=MarcoJDK
portale.datasource.platform=mysql

#MYA SOCIAL
social.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mya-social?
autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
social.datasource.username=root
social.datasource.password=MarcoJDK
social.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#MYA SERVICE
service.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mya-service?
autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
service.datasource.username=root
service.datasource.password=MarcoJDK
service.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#MYA PROVIDER SERVICE
providerservice.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mya-provider-services?
autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
providerservice.datasource.username=root
providerservice.datasource.password=MarcoJDK
providerservice.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#REGISTRAZIONE CLIENTE
registrazionecliente.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/nrc
registrazionecliente.datasource.username=root
registrazionecliente.datasource.password=MarcoJDK
registrazionecliente.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#DIGITAL PM
digitalpm.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/digital_pm
digitalpm.datasource.username=root
digitalpm.datasource.password=MarcoJDK
digitalpm.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

This should be enough to have my DB configured but i see hibernate can't create tables in my schema...i get this exception:`enter code here`

```
 org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy178.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at it.groupama.mya.dashboard.web.ui.MyADashboardUI.init(MyADashboardUI.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:693) ~[vaadin-server-7.7.9.jar:7.7.9]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:216) [vaadin-server-7.7.9.jar:7.7.9]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74) [vaadin-server-7.7.9.jar:7.7.9]
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41) [vaadin-server-7.7.9.jar:7.7.9]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422) [vaadin-server-7.7.9.jar:7.7.9]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:380) [vaadin-server-7.7.9.jar:7.7.9]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:351) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:133) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:8.5.11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]

    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2062) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:906) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2550) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2366) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2361) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1230) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:268) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.CriteriaQueryCompiler$3.getResultList(CriteriaQueryCompiler.java:254) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:329) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 70 common frames omitted


    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'digital_pm.digital_pm_log' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar:5.1.40]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.20.Final.jar:4.2.20.Final]
    ... 103 common frames omitted
```

I have created all schemas in my mysql Workbench..hibernate finds them but can't fill them with tables. Hope someone can help.

That's my Config.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource({"classpath:urls.properties","classpath:config.properties"})
@Import({
    MyADashboardPortaleModelConfig.class, 
    MyADashboardSocialModelConfig.class,
    MyADashboardServiceModelConfig.class,
    MyADashboardProviderServiceModelConfig.class,
    MyADashboardRegistrazioneClienteModelConfig.class,
    MyADashboardDigitalPmModelConfig.class

})
public class WebVaadinApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebVaadinApplication.class, args);

    }

}
```

Comment: See here: `Table 'digital_pm.digital_pm_log' doesn't exist`

Comment: Exactly what i asked for..it should create table automatically from @Table in my model. But there isn't in schema..

Comment: run `select * from digital_pm.digital_pm_log;` see if it gives error. And if it actually does not exist then what? do you want to create it using JPA?

Comment: Do you have added the entity later so that some tables are already existant? Show you entity please

Comment: This is one of my entities..I didn't added them later!

Comment: I don't want JPA create table for me LOL, hiberante should do it...

Comment: can you post you Config.java where you have referred the `.properties` file (if you have such java!),

Comment: your `spring.hibernate` properties are wrong they should start with `spring.jpa.hibernate`. Also you have a lot of datasources, so make sure that the correct one is used for creation. Also if you have multiple entity managers you will need to configure them manually as well as the datasources.

Answer (score 2):

I founded the error, this line was missing in the properties:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You can refer this link:

https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-security-rest-full/src/main/resources/persistence-h2.properties

Instead of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop`

write `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`

so that table will not be drop after program terminated